# XDocument - Object reference is not defined to an object instance

Tags: c#, .net, nullreferenceexception

When I execute the code, I've a problem on the foreach. When it executes the 'foreach' for the first time, it goes to the 'catch' by saying 'Object reference not set to an object instance'

```
String u = "C:\\Users\\Lolo\\Desktop\\fluxRSS.xml";

try{
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("myfluxRSS.xml");
    var items = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("item")
                 select new
                 {
                     title = x.Element("title").Value,
                     link = xDoc.Element("link").Value,
                     pubDate = xDoc.Element("pubDate").Value,
                     description = xDoc.Element("description").Value
                 });

    if (items != null)
    {

         foreach (var i in items){
             Console.WriteLine(i);
         }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

The RSS feed is structures like this :

```
<xml version="...">
<rss>
    <channel>
       <item>
           <!-- Rest of the tags -->
       </item>
       <item></item>
       <!-- Rest of the items -->
    </channel>
    <channel>
        <item>
            <!-- Rest of the tags -->
        </item>
        <!-- Rest of the items -->
    </channel>  
</rss>
```

Do you have a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `xDoc` instead of `x` when you creating anonymous types.And accessing Value property is throwing the exception because xDoc doesn't have a link element.Change your query like this:

```
var items = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("item")
             select new
             {
                 title = (string)x.Element("title"),
                 link = (string)x.Element("link"),
                 pubDate = (string)x.Element("pubDate"),
                 description = (string)x.Element("description")
             });
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. It was very stupid my error